# Eloquent Eager Load Constraints returning JSON String instead Object

Tags: php, json, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use Laravel 4.1 and do a Eloquent Eager Load with a One-to-Many relationship. Everything seems to work fine with this:

```
$groups = Group::with(array('points' => function($query) {
                $query->orderBy('pts', 'DESC');
         }))->get();
```

But when I try to read the property...

```
    foreach( $groups as $group ) {
        echo var_dump($group->points);
    }
```

It returns a JSON String of the object (with correct data in it)

**What should I do to get the PHP Object instead JSON?**

**Edit:**
Here are my models

```
class Group extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function points() {
        return $this->hasMany('Point');
    }

}
```

.

```
class Point extends Eloquent
{

    public function group() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Group');
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try `json_decode()` function?

Comment: I did, but that way it loses all the Laravel features, it's just an object with properties defined. Not an Eloquent ORM Instance. I think I must be doing something wrong or there should be a way to get the Eloquent Object instead the JSON String.

Comment: Try `var_export($group->points)`.

Comment: The issue wasn't the var_dump, but your suggestion helped me to understand how to show it right. Thanks.

Comment: Laravel provides a `dd()` (dump&die) helper function to debug and if any Eloquent object is printed or returned, `Laravel` converts it to `json` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the code is right, and Laravel detects how are you displaying the variable an show the more pertinent format for the use case.

`var_export()` will show the real Object anatomy. If you need to debug it.